# RegEx : Find match based on characters in a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I don't have much experience in Reg EX and that's why i am posting this question. This could be very trivial to most of you out there!

I am writing my application in C# and need to find certain matching patterns in strings.

The strings i get looks something similar to this,

```
610WBDFGFGM0122544         // (conditions 1 to 5)
XYZF44DT508755             // (condition 6)
T53497FD445                // (condition 7)
```

The above strings are just samples of what am getting. I will get many different combinations of the above strings with different numbers and alphabets.

Now from the given string i need to check certain conditions. The conditions are,

```
For given string,
```

1. IF **first 2 chars are "60" AND 3rd char is "0" or "2" AND 4th char is not "W" or "D"** THEN condition matches.
2. IF **first 2 chars are "61" AND 3rd char is "0" or "2" AND 4th char is "W" or "D"** THEN condition matches.
3. IF **first 2 chars are "62" AND 3rd char is not "0" or "2" AND 4th char is not "W" or "D"** THEN condition matches.
4. IF **first 2 chars are not "60" or "61" or "62" AND 3rd char is not"0" or "2" AND 4th char is "W" or "D"** THEN condition matches.
5. IF **first 2 chars are not "60" or "61" or "62" AND 3rd char is not"0" or "2" AND 4th char is not "W" or "D"** THEN condition matches.
6. IF **first 3 chars are "XYZ" AND string contains "T50"** THEN condition matches.
7. IF **first 2 chars are "T5" AND string contains "27" AND string ends with "5"** THEN condition matches.

Any suggestions and answers are welcome!

**UPDATE**

The reason for using RegEx in this case is because, then it's possible to externalize the RegEx patterns in a outside file and not contain in the source code. That way when a new **condition** comes up, it's easy to add the corresponding RegEx in external file without making any source code changes.

I haven't been able to make any progress in coming up with my own RegEx.

Comment: You have 7 not really hard cases which are could be made with normal string checks. Why it have to be a regex?

Comment: have you explored `string.Contains()` Method.. `SubString() method` and preforming some conditional checks based on Char or string depending on the substring.. do you have anything that you've started or coded on your own that you could show us..?

Comment: Because the plan is to externalize each RegEx pattern outside the source code and then dynamically go for the check, that way there's no need to change the source code when a new CONDITION arises.

Comment: So you want 7 regex and not 1 big regex?

Comment: Can you post the regular expressions you have tried already?

Comment: Yes i want 7 different regex. Please see UPDATE section in my original post. The reason is i could keep adding more regex's to the external file when new conditions are required.

Comment: Please see UPDATE section. I haven't been able to come up with any RegEx's as am not familiar with the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. IF **first 2 chars are "60" AND 3rd char is "0" or "2" AND 4th char is not "W" or "D"** THEN condition matches.

   `^60[02]{1}[^WD]{1}`
2. IF **first 2 chars are "61" AND 3rd char is "0" or "2" AND 4th char is "W" or "D"** THEN condition matches.

   `^61[02]{1}[WD]{1}`
3. IF **first 2 chars are "62" AND 3rd char is not "0" or "2" AND 4th char is not "W" or "D"** THEN condition matches.

   `^62[^02]{1}[^WD]{1}`
4. IF **first 2 chars are not "60" or "61" or "62" AND 3rd char is not"0" or "2" AND 4th char is "W" or "D"** THEN condition matches.

   `^((?!60|61|62).){2}[^02]{1}[WD]{1}`
5. IF **first 2 chars are not "60" or "61" or "62" AND 3rd char is not"0" or "2" AND 4th char is not "W" or "D"** THEN condition matches.

   `^((?!60|61|62).){2}[^02]{1}[^WD]{1}`
6. IF **first 3 chars are "XYZ" AND string contains "T50"** THEN condition matches.

   `^XYZ.*(T50).*$`
7. IF **first 2 chars are "T5" AND string contains "27" AND string ends with "5"** THEN condition matches.

   `^T5.*(27).*5$`

Answer (score 1):

To match a specific string/word:

```
60
```

To match certain chars:

```
[WD]
```

To match all except certain chars:

```
[^WD]
```

To skip any sequence of chars:

```
.*
```

To match a char at the end:

```
5$
```

To match anything but 61 and 62:

```
((?!61|62).){2}
```

Example: starts with A, then B or C, then anything but D, containing E, ending with F:

```
A[BC][^D].*E.*F$
```

That should allow you to piece together the ones you need.